# Qt 5.11, QWidget and creating a window and connecting to signals

Tags: c++, qt, signals

I am dynamically creating new windows using:

```
QWidget* pobjWin = new QWidget();    
pobjNode->setWidget(pobjWin);
pobjWin->resize(intWidth, intHeight);
pobjWin->move(intX, intY);
```

This works and in my application I have 3 windows, I want to connect to the various signals that according to the online documentation are:

```
activeChanged
contentOrientationChanged
focusObjectChanged
...
```

In my application as an example I connect to these signals with:

```
QObject::connect(pobjWin, SIGNAL(activeChanged(void))
                ,pobjSubNode
                ,SLOT(windowSlotActiveChanged(void)));
```

The pointer 'pobjSubNode' points to a class which has defined slots for each of the signals I am connecting to.

When I run this and the connects are executed I get:

```
2018-10-25 16:26:39.550030+0100 XMLMPAM[2048:219099] QObject::connect: No such signal QWidget::activeChanged(void) in ../XMLMPAM/clsMainWnd.cpp:733
```

I think the issue is because the pobjWin points to a QWidget and not a QWindow, but I couldn't find an example that doesn't create a window this way.

[Edit] Using the new connection method:

```
   QObject::connect(pobjWin, &QWindow::activeChanged
                   ,pobjSubNode, &clsXMLnode::windowSlotActiveChanged);
```

The prototypes for activeChanged and windowSlotActiveChanged are identical.   But when I build with this implementation I get:

```
/Users/simonplatten/XMLMPAM/clsMainWnd.cpp:733: error: no matching function for call to 'connect'
                QObject::connect(pobjWin, &QWindow::activeChanged
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[Edit2] I've changed the connect to:

```
QObject::connect(pobjWin->windowHandle(), &QWindow::activeChanged
                                ,pobjSubNode, &clsXMLnode::windowSlotActiveChanged);
```

Now I get:

```
2018-10-25 17:37:22.299066+0100 XMLMPAM[2930:423194] QObject::connect: invalid null parameter
```

Having just assigned:

```
QWindow* pobjW2 = pobjWin->windowHandle();
```

I can see in the debugger that pobjW2 is NULL, which explains the error.

Changing the line:

```
QWidget* pobjWin = new QWidget();
```

To:

```
QWindow* pobjWin = new QWindow();
```

Has fixed the connection problems, once I fixed all the methods to use the QWindow versions instead of the QWidget versions, but now I don't get any visible windows...investigating.  Its odd that the methods in QWindow have different names to those that do the exact same job in QWidget.

[Edit 3] After fixing the problems with help on correcting the connection and inserting a call to showNormal before creating the connections.  The code is exactly as originally posted with a call to pobjWin->showNormal before any connects.

Comment: Don't use the old `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros in new code, please (except in rare cases where you *have to*). Use the new compile-time-checked member-function-pointer based syntax instead.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, thank you, do you have a link to an example?

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax , http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html#

Comment: @JesperJuhl, when I tried to implement the code as shown in the example I get: no matching function for call to 'connect'

Comment: That's an improvement. Now your incorrect code fails at compile time, instead of compiling and just doing the wrong thing at run time. Although, a linker error indicates you probably did some new thing wrong  as well. Show your updated code please.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, will edit post now.

Comment: Please show the *entire* error message.

Comment: **QWidget is different from QWindow**

Comment: @eyllanesc, if I change QWindow to QWidget then QWidget has no function called activeChanged....I think it should stay QWindow and I should change the creation from new QWidget to new QWindow ?

Comment: @SPlatten change `QObject::connect(pobjWin, &QWindow::activeChanged, ..` to `QObject::connect(pobjWin->windowHandle(), &QWindow::activeChanged, ...`

Comment: @SPlatten What you should get is the QWindow of the QWidget, so that you understand QWindow is an object shared by all the widgets in the same window.

Comment: @SPlatten Note that QWindow is only created when the window is visible.

Comment: @eyllanesc, I realise that, but that doesn't help me create the connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, I acknowledge the input from eylanesc, thank you.

I had to add a call to:

```
pobjWin->showNormal();
```

Before attempting the signal / slot connections, an example of a signal and slot connection now looks like:

```
QObject::connect(pobjWin->windowHandle(), &QWindow::activeChanged
                ,pobjSubNode, &clsXMLnode::windowSlotActiveChanged);
```